# How to scroll to a certain Div on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using the following code to scroll to a div, it scroll to this div and then scrolls back up to the top of the page why?

```
$("#Qtags").click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({'scrollTop' : $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top},1000)
    return false;
});
```

i have the dom ready function in place

Comment: That's because you might have called it soon before completion of page load. Call it after the page is completely loaded.

Comment: i have the dom ready function in place.

Comment: Then I guess it's from the cache. Try scrolling to the top first (manually), then reload (hard refresh) the page.

Comment: Can you provide some more code? what your href attribute contain?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this :-

```
$('html,body').animate({ scrollTop: $(this.hash).offset().top }, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this : change the href attribute to 'javascript:void(0)',add this attribute  to='(your target div's id)'

```
$("#Qtags").click(function(){
    $('html, body').animate({'scrollTop' : $('#'+$(this).attr('to')).offset().top+'px'},1000)
    return false;
});
```

Hope this can help

Answer (score -1):

You can use:

`window.location.hash = '#'+divId`

if you just want to <del>scroll</del> jump down to that `div` tag location. Try `window.location.hash = '#footer'` on this page.

Comment: Thats not scrolling, that is just jumping.